# How set margin between default keyboard and bottom side?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement the following behavior:
1) I have my own bottom bar with some buttons

[image]

2) When I click on button "keyboard" I want to show default virtual keyboard with one textView. But my "bottom bar" should be visible as the following image.

[image]

I checked a lot of articles but I can not find how to implement it. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That is might be **VERY** hard, maybe even impossible. You will need to look into using the window manager to create an extra window at the bottom of the screen that is somehow "reserved" (I haven't looked into this, so I'm not sure it can even be done). Once you have figured out how to do that, hopefully better behaved input methods ("default" keyboards) should be adjusted to the reduced screen area.

Unfortunately it is more likely your button keyboard will be the one that gets adjusted, probably by being drawn over or shunted above the keyboard. But then, I haven't looked at what flags are available for creating new windows.

Hope that gives you an idea of where to start looking anyway, good luck!